# Are all metric tensors diagonal?

Tags: differential-geometry

If I understand correctly, one way to get the components of a metric tensor (treating it like a matrix here) is to look at the $ds$ interval. Isn't that interval always in terms of sums of $dr^2+d\theta^2$ etc, meaning that the metric tensor will only have nonzero values for $x^ix^j$ when $i=j$?

If this is not the case, can anyone give an example?

Comment: The carrot is a caret, really.

Comment: Oh haha oops, thanks.

Comment: I would vote both for the answer but it seems I can't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Being diagonal is a coordinate-dependent concept: the components of the matrix associated to the metric tensor depend on the coordinate system you use. Thus a very simple example of a non-diagonal metric is the standard Euclidean metric $\delta = dx^2 + dy^2$ on $\mathbb R^2$ in the coordinate system $(x,z) = (x, x+y)$, where it has the coordinate expression $$\delta = dx^2 + d(z-x)^2 = 2dx^2 + dz^2 - 2 dx dz.$$

Comment: One can always orthogonalize a symmetric tensor. Note too that one could normalize, thus having only 1,-1,0 on the diagonal. This corresponds to the equivalence principle of choosing a local inertial frame.

Answer (score 5):

No, in fact, there's some very famous solutions that have non-diagonal metrics. Such as the [Kerr metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric) for a rotating black hole in General relativity.